# Restricted Integer Programming

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, integer-programming

The integer feasibility problem is NP-complete:

$Ax=b, x \geq 0, x \mbox{ integer}$

$A$ contains elements in $\mathbb{R}$

If we restrict this:

$A$ contains only elements in:

1. $\{1,0\}$
2. $\{1,0,-1\}$
3. $\mathbb{N}$
4. $\mathbb{Z}$

Does this change anything in term of hardness?

Can all these problems be reduced to each other?

(Can it be for example that there is polynominaltime-algorithm for 1. but not for 4.?)

Comment: Might be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846149/integer-programming-feasibility-is-np-what

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All four problems are NP-complete.

Let me start by proving two easy results:

- Your problem #3 is NP-complete, even when the matrix has only a single row, as explained here: [Complexity of a subset sum variant](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/8970/5038).
- This implies that #4 is NP-complete as well, as #3 is a special case of #4.

Now for the strong result: Your problem #1 is NP-complete.  The proof of this is a bit more involved, but I'll show a reduction from ZOE to your #1, where ZOE is a problem that is known to be NP-complete.

In particular, here is the definition of ZOE:

ZERO-ONE EQUATIONS (ZOE)
Input: a $m\times n$ matrix $A$, all of whose entries are 0 or 1
Goal: Find a $n$-vector $x$, all of whose entries are 0 or 1, such that $Ax=1$, where $1$ denotes the all-ones vector

The ZOE problem is NP-complete.  This is proven in Chapter 8.3 of *Algorithms* (Sanjoy Dasgupta, Christos Papadimitriou, Umesh Vazirani).  The proof proceeds by reducing 3SAT to 3D Matching, and then reducing 3D Matching to ZOE.

Now we can reduce ZOE to #1, as follows.  If we have an instance of ZOE $A$, we transform it as follows.  For each variable $x_i$ of the ZOE instance, we add another variable $x^*_i$ and an equation $x_i + x^*_i = 1$.  (This has the effect of forcing $x_i$ to be either 0 or 1, since we'll require $x_i \ge 0$ and $x^*_i \ge 0$ and $x_i,x^*_i$ are integers.)  Thus, if the ZOE instance had a $m\times n$ matrix $A$, we now obtain $m+n$ equations in $2n$ unknowns, corresponding to some matrix $A'$.  In other words, we obtain a problem instance $A'x' = b$ where $b=1$ is the all-ones vector, and where every entry of $A'$ is 0 or 1.  This is now an instance of your problem #1.  This instance of your problem #1 has a feasible solution if and only if the original ZOE instance has a feasible solution.  This proves that any efficient algorithm to your #1 in turn yields an efficient algorithm for ZOE -- but since ZOE is NP-complete, it follows that #1 is NP-complete as well.

It follows from this result that #2, #3, and #4 are NP-complete as well, as #1 is a special case of them.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: (3) and (4) can be reduced to (2), at the price of increasing the problem size by a factor in $O(\log N)$, where $N$ is the greatest matrix entry in the original problem. One way of doing this (possibly suboptimal) is to have for each original variable $x$ pairs of new variables $x_i,\bar x_i$ ($0\le i\le \log N$) representing $2^ix$, which is enforced by the additional constraints $x_i-\bar x_i=0$ and $x_{i+1}-x_i-\bar x_i=0$. Now replace each term $mx$ in the linear constraints by the appropriate combination of $x_i$, and you are done.

Comment: can you explain this a bit more precise?